# Merging two arrays into one

Tags: bash

Suppose I have 2 arrays X and Y in which each element is a number. I want to make another array SUM so that `SUM[i]=X[i]+Y[i]`.

Can I do this without using loops?

Comment: I don't think so. Bash doesn't have any operators that process entire arrays.

Answer (score 2):

```
 C[i]='expr ${A[i]} + ${B[i]}'
```

will do the job

Comment: The guy wants to process whole arrays without using a loop not just one.